# How to Create a Post in WordPress Programmatically

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I would like to know how I create posts in WordPress programmatically for around seven different posts?

I tried:

```
 <div class="demo">     
<?php global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post); ?>
</div>
```

It did not display anything?

Comment: The WP docs aren't as complete as I'd like, but simple stuff like this can be searched for trivially. Please always do a thorough search before asking questions - it will make you a more self-sufficient programmer.

Comment: @yan.kun actually that is not what I'm looking for I have tried everything and it hasn't worked.

Comment: So what have you tried? If we on stackoverflow don't know what you've done so far we can't help you.

Comment: No, the `wp_insert_post()` call won't display anything - that creates a post in WP programmatically, which is _exactly_ what you asked for. If you refresh your blog, it will show the new post. Do check the return value of the function though, in case you are getting an insert error.

Answer (score 23):

```
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Comment: It didn't display anything?

Comment: No, the wp_insert_post() call won't display anything - that creates a post in WP programmatically, which is exactly what you asked for. If you refresh your blog, it will show the new post. Do check the return value of the function though, in case you are getting an insert error

Comment: [documentation of wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) with (many) more options.